# SVG path commands "s" and "t"

Tags: svg

When implementing `"s"` (relative cubic Bezier arc) and `"t"` (relative quadratic Bezier arc) commands are the coordinates of the implicitly defined control point used as base for next relative coordinate or not?

In other words consider the following cubic arc:

[image: cubic arc example]

- `cp` current point
- `ip` implicit control point computed mirroring last control point from previous arc
- `ep` explicit control point
- `fp` final point of the arc

Should be the relative coordinates of `ep` use as base `ip` (the implicit point) or should they be relative to `cp` (the current point of the path)?

In the official documentation I found this unclear and no example using relative coordinates in these cases.

Comment: Can you just confirm that you're talking about Bezier curves? You mention "arc" in the question.

Comment: Sorry... yes, I'm talking about Bezier cubic and quadratic arcs (`s` and `t` codes of svg `path` elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) states that an uppercase **S** expects absolute coordinates, while a lower case **s** expects relative coordinates. Similar for **T** (absolute) and **t** (relative).

**EDIT** - relative to the *current* point - sorry, should have been explicit. The same document linked to above includes the following:

> For the relative versions of the commands, all coordinate values are relative to the current point at the start of the command

Comment: Ok. But relative to WHAT? To the current point or to the implicit control point? Are `ep` coordinates in the picture relative to `ip` or to `cp`?

Comment: So you mean that even `fp` coordinates are relative to `cp`?

Answer (score 10):

The rules are

1. When using relative mode the coordinates are relative to the current point **at the start of the command**
2. In case of a command "chain" when multiple coordinates are given without repeating the command the base point **is updated after each repetition**

For example the simple path

```
m 100,100 100,0 0,100 -100,0 0,-100
```

describes a square from (100,100) to (200,200)

[image: simple relative path]

(the `l` "line-to" command shown in red is implicit if multiple coordinates pairs are provided for a "m" command)

The important point to note is that the relative "base" for coordinates is updated at each turning point. This is somewhat deceiving in the documentation because the syntax of `m` command is described as accepting `(x,y)+` as parameter so the reader could be tricked into thinking that the relative base will change only at the end of the entire sequence of points.

Now let's consider the Bezier cubic path

```
m 100,100 c 25,25 75,25 100,0 s 25,125 0,100 -75,-25 -100,0
```

[image: bezier arcs example]

The two red control points are computed automatically by mirroring the last control point. The red `s` command is implicit because four points followed `s`.

For a cubic Bezier arc command the two control points and the end point are relative to the same start point (they're not relative to the previous in sequence) but at each arc the base point for relative coordinate computation is updated.